# Making a switch button using "threading" module for executing while loop

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, python-multithreading

I want to make program which a has button , when we click on button , it will run some functions infinitely and the button turn into another button such that when we click it second time , it will stop the infinite process. In my codes you can see my aim.

When i do not click on button , there is a text on button such as "start" , and when i click first time , it starts an infinite process such as printing two functions. After that , the button turn into a red color button which has text "stop" and when you click it second time , it stops this infinite while loop.

**What I want:** I want to convert my button into a switch such that when i click it second time , it stop the process , but be ready for running it again. What i meant is that when i click it second time , it stop the process and its color be green and text = "start" , again.I want this clicking process foreover such as  a switch of a lamb.When you click it , it will be ready for the other process.

**My problem:** When i click the button second time , my code gives error. It did not turn into "start" button again". Can you help me to fix it.

**Note:** I am beginner in "threading" module ,so please be clear in your answers.

**MY CODE:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
class Uygulama(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.araclar()
    def araclar(self):
        self.etiket1 = Label(text="WELCOME TO HERE", fg="blue", font="Times 15 bold", 
                      bg="grey")
        self.etiket1.pack()
        
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start, args=(self.stop_event,))
        self.dugme1 = Button( text="Start Greeting", command=self.start_cmd, 
                             fg="black", bg="green", font="bold")
        self.dugme1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.65)

        self.etiket3 = Label(font="Times 14 bold", bg="grey")
        self.etiket3.place(rely=0.30, relx=0.08)

    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello there")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there")

    def start_cmd(self):
        self.dugme1.config(text="Stop greeting", command=self.stop_cmd,fg="black", bg="red", 
                             font="bold")
        self.thread.start()

    def stop_cmd(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.destroy()

    def start(self, stop_event):
        self.etiket3.config(text="You are greeting them !",  font="Times 17 bold")                              
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            self.say_hello()
            self.say_hi()

pencere = Tk()
pencere.geometry("500x500+400+30")
pencere.resizable(width=False, height=False)
pencere.configure(bg="grey")
uyg = Uygulama()
mainloop()
```

**The error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "/home/sunw/Desktop/uygulama.py", line 34, in stop_cmd
  self.destroy()
AttributeError: 'Uygulama' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

** ADDING DESTROY:**

```
def destroy(self):
    self.dugme1.config(text="Start Greeting", command=self.start_cmd,
                       fg="black", bg="green", font="bold")
```

**New error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)
File "/home/sunw/Desktop/uygulama.py", line 35, in start_cmd
  self.thread.start()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 930, in start
 raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

Comment: You said the code gives you an error. Can you please post the full error traceback? Also you have `self.destroy` but there is no destroy method and your class only inherits from `object`. Also why aren't you passing in a master for all of those widgets? Btw `tkinter` doesn't like to be called from different threads, so itay reside to crash.

Comment: @TheLizzard i have added the error part

Comment: The error is telling you that it doesn't know what `self.destroy` should do. It hasn't been defined.

Comment: @TheLizzard please see the edition

Comment: @TheLizzard i handled to turn into a switch , but it says that threads can be used once

Comment: Move the `self.stop_event = threading.Event()` and the `self.thread = threading.Thread(...)` inside `start_cmd`.

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks a lot , if you write this as answer , i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

As explained, not sure what was the purpose for self.destroy(), just remove that.

Also threads once defined can be started only once, see https://bugs.python.org/issue751260

Remove self.thread declaration from araclar, and have start and stop functions as below:

```
def start_cmd(self):
    self.dugme1.config(text="Stop greeting", command=self.stop_cmd, fg="black", bg="red",
                       font="bold")
    self.stop_event.clear()
    threading.Thread(target=self.start, args=(self.stop_event,)).start()

def stop_cmd(self):
    self.stop_event.set()
    self.dugme1.config(text="Start Greeting", command=self.start_cmd,
                         fg="black", bg="green", font="bold")
```

Comment: this is the same as the comment  of @TheLizzard

Comment: @mamg2909 Removing the `destroy` method with stop the button from resetting its `text`/`command`. Therefore, the `destroy` method is needed

Comment: @TheLizzard to reset the text you just need the config method as my example shows in `stop_cmd`. I just tested the code ant it works fine.